# How can I access my redux store's current state outside of a connected component?

Tags: react-redux

I am working on a project where a user can get get various movie or music suggestions based on their user settings. I currently have a three reducers that manages the movie screen, music screen and user settings.

I notice that when dispatching my actions, I always have to add my user settings as an argument, for example:

```
getMusic(query, { ...userSettings})
getMovie(query, { ...userSettings})
```

My question is: since user settings will always be included in my dispatched actions, is there another way I can pass in the state of my **userSettings** to my various function calls without having to connect my **userSettings** at the component level?

Comment: This is me from the future, the question doesn't really make sense. You shouldn't want to access redux state outside of a connected component.

I think the question I wanted to ask was how can I DRY up my dispatched actions. To which current day me would suggest looking into selectors: https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider adding the [middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware/) [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to your project.

Your action creator can then look something like this:

```
const getMusic = (query) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { userSettings } = getState();
    // do something with userSettings
    dispatch(someOtherActionCreator(...));
}
```

Nice thing about this is that you get hold of the complete redux store's state when the action is dispatched.